# Having trouble returning a String in a function with C

Tags: c, arrays, return

I have a function `char enterComponent()` and I would like to have it ask the user for a string `name`, and then return the name to where it was called.

This is the code I have

```
char enterComponent(){
    char name[8];
    printf("    enter next component name:  ");
    sscanf("%s", &name);
    return name;      
}
```

and this is what the debugger tells me

```
warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

I was wondering if someone can tell me what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Do not return a pointer to an object with automatic storage duration and use `scanf` to read a string from `stdin`.

Basically change your function to:

```
void enterComponent(char *name)
{
    printf("    enter next component name:  ");
    scanf("%s", name);
}
```

That you could call this way:

```
 char name[256]; // reserve enough space, use fgets / sscanf for safety

 enterComponent(name);

 printf("%s\n", name);  // prints your string
```

Comment: `static char name[]`  would also work right, is there a prefered way though?

Comment: @tesseract The preferred way is to avoid `static` objects when you can.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is defined as returning a single character. It should return a `char *`. However, you must not return your local variable `name`, since it is allocated on the stack, and will be overwritten once the function calling enterComponent() makes another call.
Either you pass a buffer to the function, for the entered value to be returned in, or `malloc` memory for the return value (and don't forget to `free` it later!)

Answer (score 0):

You should correctly declare the function that it would return a pointer to a dynamically allocated character array. For examoke

```
char * enterComponent()
{
    const size_t N = 8;
    char *name = malloc( N * sizeof( char ) );

    printf("    enter next component name:  ");

    if ( name ) fgets( name, N, stdin );

    return name;      
}
```

Of course you could allocate more than 8 characters, For example you could define N as for example 50.

Do not forget to free the returned pointer when it wiil not be needed any more.

```
free( name );
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm looking it over and wondering why it prints out `"    enter next component name:  "` `"    enter next component name:  "` twice when the function is called the first time.

But then after that, it only prints once.

Comment: @johnnyboyyy  It seems because you print this message twice: before the function call and inside the function body.